# Advise on database table design, table of estimates

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database-design, relational-database

I am new to database design (have read a couple of tutorials though).

In my program I need to store records of time estimates. 
An estimate for a workpackage is consist of estimates in hours for 36 timeperiods (month).

My plan is to have the following columns:

- id INTEGER (Primary key)
- workpackageId INTEGER (Foreign key)
- competendId INTEGER (Foreign key)
- M36 SMALLINT UNSIGNED
- M35 SMALLINT UNSIGNED
- M34 SMALLINT UNSIGNED
- .....
- M1 SMALLINT UNSIGNED
- created DATETIME
- modified DATETIME

M1 to M36 is actually estimations of work time for a period of one month. 
A workpackage that can be implemented in one calender month time will only have estimates in the M1 column.
A workpackage that would at a minimum require 6 calender month will have estimates in the M1-M6 columns.

I might need to get even more data in there and add separat values for MIN (LIKELY) MAX estimates seperately for each timeperiod.

I am sure there is a smarter way to do this but I dont know how...

Any suggestions would be greatly appriciated...

Best regards // Claes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be my approach

```
Table Jobs
JobID -- Don't just use ID
workpackageId 
competendId 
CreatedOn
ModifiedOn


Table TimePeriod
TimePeriodID
TimePeriodDesc -- this is your M1, M2, etc

Table Times
TimeID
JobID  -- fk to Jobs
TimePeriodID -- fk to TimePeriod
EstimateType -- Min, Max, etc
EstimateValue INT -- pop your estimate in here
CreatedOn  -- No modify, just use the most recent created for each to allow audit history
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this approach.

Comment: Not sure about the 'No modify' though.
Estimations M1--M36 are closely coupled and when a job is reestimated all old M1-->M36 estimes are no longer valid.

Example: 
Version 1: Job  estimated to 3 month, 60 h per month, total 180 h (M1 60, M2 60, M3 60, M4-->M36 0

Version 2: Job  estimated to 2 month, 90 h per month, total 180 h (M1 90, M2 90, M3-->M36 0

If allowing multiple instances and only looking at the newest I suppost you would always need to add 36 rows in Times for each job and update the all if an individual estimate change.

Have I understood your design correctly?

Comment: @ClaesJohannesson You would only need to add the rows that are subject to change. What you don't want is for someone to turn around and ask what the estimate was a couple of months ago, only to tell them that you don't have the data any more. You won't take up much more space this way, but will have  amuch more robust dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I guess M1-26 are some estimations...
You might want to extract it to another table, which will give you possibility to be more adjustable on that.

See this example to get what I'm talking about and adjust it to your needs:

### Table WRKPKGS

- id INTEGER (Primary key)
- workpackageId INTEGER (Foreign key)
- competendId INTEGER (Foreign key)
- wrk_time_id INTEGER (Foreign key)

### Table TIMEPERIODS

- id INTEGER (Primary key)
- name VARCHAR
- estimated_time SMALLINT UNSIGNED

### Table TIME_WRKPKGS

- id (Primary key)
- id_time
- id_wrkpkg

This is many to many relation which clarifies your database schema.
Now when you will want to add for example M20 estimation you will need to do the following:

1. Add job to WRKPKGS (remember id)
2. Add TimePeriod with name M20 (remember id)
3. Add linking record in TIME_WRKPKGS (use ids generated above)

And you have what you want. Now modifying this is easy - if you want to add min/max estimations, you just extend the Timeperiods table and you're done

Comment: M1 to M36 is actually estimations of work time for a period of one month. 
A workpackage that can be implemented in one calender month time will only have estimates in the M1 column.
A workpackage that would at a minimum require 6 calender month will have estimates in the M1-M6 columns.

Comment: So - extend time period with int column which would hold estimation value - and I believe you're done